# Is it possible to call a specialized integer templated method?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a non-template class that is itself used as a template parameter of another class.
This class is used to abstract the underlying representation of some data.
Ideally, one of the method of this class should be integer parameterized.

E.g  :
    typedef double Price;

```
enum Side
{
  BUY,
  SELL
};

struct Book
{
  template <Side side>
  int getLimit(Price price) const
  {
    return 0;
  }
};

struct Spotter
{
  template <typename Book>
  Price compute(Price startPrice, const Book& book)
  {
    int limit = book.getLimit<BUY>(startPrice);
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Now when compiling with gcc, I get 
"error: no match for 'operator<' in book->Book::getLimit < (Side)0u"

It looks like a parsing error as if the grammar does not allow object.method(args) to be written in the first place.

Note that in my real code, the compute() method is itself parameterized by a side parameter, which is forwarded to the getLimit() method.

Is there a way to make this work  ?

Comment: `book.template getLimit<BUY>(startPrice);`

Comment: Tx ! Didn't know this syntax, you made my day !